# Facing AttributeError: for 'tag_' using Spacy in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I'm using Spacy for "POS Tagging" and getting below error. I have a dataframe, which has the column "description" in which I need to extract the POS for each word

Dataframe :

```
No.      Description
1        My net is not working
2        I will be out for dinner
3        Can I order food
4        Wifi issue
```

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
read_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\abc\\def\\pqr\\Data\\training_data.csv', encoding="utf-8")
entity = []
for parsed_doc in read_data['Description']:
    doc = nlp(parsed_doc)
    a = [(X.text, X.tag_) for X in doc.ents]
    entity.append(a)
```

The above code is throwing error:

> Error : AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no
>   attribute 'tag_'

**However, the same code is working fine for "Label" attribute and also if I use a single sentence**

```
doc = nlp('can you please help me to install wifi')
for i in doc:
    print (i.text, i.tag_)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because things like `ents` or `chunks` are Spans i.e. collections of tokens. Hence you need to iterate over their individual tokens to get their attributes like `tag` or `tag_`

```
>>> doc = nlp(u'Mr. Best flew to New York on Saturday morning.')
>>> [(X.text, X.tag_) for X in doc.ents]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no attribute 'tag_'
>>> [(X.text, X.tag_) for Y in doc.ents for X in Y]
[('Best', 'NNP'), ('New', 'NNP'), ('York', 'NNP'), ('Saturday', 'NNP'), ('morning', 'NN')]
```